# Auto-detect new locale files (instead of having to restart Rails server)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I don't like that I have to manually restart my Rails server again and again after important files are changed (e.g. in the `config` directory).

So I wrote a small script that uses the rerun gem which restarts the server automatically:

```
rerun --pattern '{Gemfile.lock,config/application.rb,config/environment.rb,config/environments/development.rb,config/initializers/*.rb,lib/**/*.rb,config/database.yml}' --no-growl --signal INT --background --clear -- rails s
```

More info also on my blog post: http://lsd4coders.muheimwebdesign.ch/2014/05/automatically-restart-rails-server-when-needed/

So far, so good, but sadly rerun doesn't find out about **new** files, so if I create a new file under e.g. `config/locales`, I still have to do a manual restart. This is pretty annoying. And I can't simply watch for all translation files like `config/locales/*.yml` because this would cause a restart on every changed file, too!

Is there another, maybe better approach? Can I force Rails somehow to look out for new locale files itself?

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
rerun --pattern '{Gemfile.lock,config/application.rb,config/environment.rb,config/environments/development.rb,config/initializers/*.rb,lib/**/*.rb,config/**/*.yml}' --no-growl --signal INT --background --clear -- rails s
```

won't work?

Comment: This also restarts the server whenever a locale file is **changed**. I update the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Quickly checked on rerun documentation and it seems it does not make distinction between change and create of file. Perhaps posting on their issue tracker would be a good option